# Array em php com PDO

Tags: php, html5

precisei mudar minha conexão mysqli para pdo, e estou "apanhando" na hora de apontar qual index que quero imprimir, olhe o exemplo do modelo com mysql:

```
$Busca = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM OrdemServico WHERE Status = '$Status'", $con -> conexaoMysqlP()) or die (mysql_error());
$Consulta = mysql_fetch_array($Busca);
<?php 
do{
<table>
<tr>
<td width="50px"><span class="RAT"><?=$Consulta["RAT"] ?></span></td>
<td width="150px"><?=$Consulta["Clientes"]?></td>
<tr/><table>
}while ($Consulta = mysql_fetch_assoc($Busca));
```

Agora preciso dele em PDO, mas não consigo imprimir separado, apenas todos e com o index.

```
$Pesquisar = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM OrdemServico order by Status");
$Pesquisar -> execute();
$result = $Pesquisar->fetchAll();
<table>
<tr>
<td width="50px"><?=$Consulta["RAT"] ?></td>
<td width="150px"><?=$Consulta["Clientes"]?></td>
<tr/><table>
}while ($result = $Pesquisar->fetchAll());
```

Espero que alguém possa me ajudar, e obrigado pela atenção!^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente você precisa de algo assim:

```
<?php

  ...

  $Pesquisar = $pdo->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM OrdemServico order by Status' );
  $Pesquisar->execute();
  $result = $Pesquisar->fetchAll();
  foreach( $result as $Consulta ) {
?>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="50px"><?= $Consulta['RAT'] ?></td>
      <td width="150px"><?= $Consulta['Clientes']?></td>
    <tr/>
  <table>
<?php
  }
```

A razão é que o `fetchAll()` já vai trazer todas as linhas por padrão, não adianta executar mais de uma vez. No caso, o `foreach` vai servir para iterar uma a uma.

Uma maneira mais parecida com seu código original seria usar `fetch` no lugar do `fetchAll`:

```
<?php

  ...

  $Pesquisar = $pdo->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM OrdemServico order by Status' );
  $Pesquisar->execute();
  while( $Consulta = $Pesquisar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
?>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="50px"><?= $Consulta['RAT'] ?></td>
      <td width="150px"><?= $Consulta['Clientes'] ?></td>
    <tr/>
  <table>
<?php
  }
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, o problema foi resolvido.... coisa simples rsrrs! Mais uma vez um muito obrigado!